# How do I completely drain a Topic Subscription?

Tags: azureservicebus

I have roughly 1,400 messages in a Topic Subscription. When I go to do a batch receive, such as with [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer), of, say, 500 messages. I don't get nearly that many back. Here is a clip of the console from SBE.

```
<12:09:45> The subscription billingpackage for the checkoutsubmitted topic has been successfully retrieved.
<12:09:46> [36] messages received from the subscription [billingpackage].
<12:10:28> The subscription billingpackage for the checkoutsubmitted topic has been successfully retrieved.
<12:10:28> [120] messages received from the subscription [billingpackage].
<12:11:59> The subscription billingpackage for the checkoutsubmitted topic has been successfully retrieved.
<12:11:59> [40] messages received from the subscription [billingpackage].
<12:13:14> The subscription billingpackage for the checkoutsubmitted topic has been successfully retrieved.
<12:13:15> [66] messages received from the subscription [billingpackage].
<12:14:12> The subscription billingpackage for the checkoutsubmitted topic has been successfully retrieved.
<12:14:12> [140] messages received from the subscription [billingpackage].
```

Why am I not getting the 500 I'm asking for? I'm on Standard tier, if that matters.

Comment: What's the size of your messages? Do you have any competing consumers by any chance?

Comment: @SeanFeldman they are about 1.3 KB in size, and no, no competing consumers. This is part of some greenfield work so it's my own sandbox, currently.

Comment: 500 messages at 1.3 KB each would not fit into a single batch, but it shouldn't be that many batches either. Has to do with how broker decides what to send.

Comment: @SeanFeldman if it were a consistent amount, I could understand this. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a discernible pattern. The only difference from one message to the next is the Guid I use as the MessageId so they should be uniform.

Answer (score 2):

That is expected. The number you specify in a batch receive is only the maximum number of messages to be retrieved in a batch. Actual number of messages received could be anywhere between 1 and max. If a batch receive call returns less than the max number specified, it doesn't mean there are only so many messages in the queue. Only indication that a queue or subscription is empty is when a receive call returns null. In your case, you should continue receiving in batches until it returns null.

Comment: I think the question is why a receive batch call for an entity that has way more than the specified max number of items to return returns less than it _could_. I.e. if a queue has way over 500 messages, messages can easily fit into maximum message size, and batch requested was 500, it's expected to anticipate 500 messages returned rather than query in a loop.